# RxSwift, invoking a network call

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am new to Rx and trying to one network call.

i mange to do that as follow:

```
struct Genre: Codable {
var genres: [Genres]?
}

struct Genres: Codable {
var id: Int?
var name: String?
 }

final class GenreViewModel {

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

var networking: Networking!

let getGeners = PublishRelay<[Genres]>()

var items: PublishRelay<[Genres]>?
var itemsDriver: Driver<[Genres]>?
let isLoading: Driver<Bool>


init(networking: Networking = Networking()) {
    self.networking = networking

    
    let shouldLoadItems = Observable.merge(
    ).debug("merge.debug()")
    .startWith(())
    
    let gg = shouldLoadItems.flatMap {
        networking.preformNetwokTask(
            endPoint: TheMoviedbApi.genre,
            type: Genre.self)
            .debug(" network call")
    }
    
    isLoading = Observable.merge(
        shouldLoadItems.map { true },
        gg.map { _ in false }
    )
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false).debug(" is loading")
    
    itemsDriver = gg
        .map { $0.genres! }
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: []).debug("drive")
    
}
```

i am trying to figure a way of doing it without "let shouldLoadItems".
something like that:

```
final class GenreViewModel {

let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

var networking: Networking!

let getGeners = PublishRelay<[Genres]>()

var items: PublishRelay<[Genres]>?
var itemsDriver: Driver<[Genres]>?
let isLoading: Driver<Bool>


init(networking: Networking = Networking()) {
    self.networking = networking
    
   let geners =  getGeners
        .flatMap { geners in
            networking.preformNetwokTask(
                endPoint: TheMoviedbApi.genre,             
               type: Genre.self)
              .debug(" network call not in use")
       }.startWith(())
       .share()


    
    isLoading = Observable.merge(
        shouldLoadItems.map { true },
        gg.map { _ in false }
    )
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false).debug(" is loading")

    
    itemsDriver = geners
        .map { $0.genres! }
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: []).debug("drive")
    
}
```

The vc:

```
func bindRx() {
    viewModel.isLoading
        .drive(hud.rx.animation)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
   
        
    
    viewModel.itemsDriver?.drive(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: GenreCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: GenreCollectionViewCell.self)) { (row,item,cell) in
        cell.config(item: item)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Yet  let geners  not called.
what am i missing out?

Comment: Looks like you're not using `subscribe` and `drive` on your `Observable` and `Driver` respectively. (Don't forget the `dispose`, too. )

Comment: @Vym can you please tell me where should i subscribe?

Comment: Do you really have both a `Genres` type and a `Genre` type? Can you show those structs?

Comment: What is the cause of the network call?

Comment: Subjects and Relays should never be defined using `var` always use `let` for them.

Comment: @DanielT. the cause is to get genres , and i am adding the structs

Comment: @ironRoei that's the effect you want to achieve. What causes that effect? What action is supposed to trigger it?

Comment: @DanielT.the init viewModel.
I want the call to start when i init the vm

Comment: @ironRoei Okay, and what is supposed to happen after the request completes?

Comment: @DanielT.the collectionview in the vc will show each genre in a different cell:
 
        viewModel.itemsDriver?.drive(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: GenreCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: GenreCollectionViewCell.self)) { (row,item,cell) in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect all the questions in the comments was a bit of a pain, but the thing that was missing in this question was the "reactive" part of "functional reactive programming".

In FRP, a network request doesn't happen in isolation. It's usually triggered by an event producer and feeds an event consumer. In order for the request to happen at all, an event consumer must exist.

A view model, on its own and not connected to anything, does nothing. In order for your networking event to happen, *something* must be listening for the result. Your view model is like the plumbing in your house. The water doesn't flow unless someone opens a tap.

```swift
struct GenreViewModel {
    let items: Observable<[Genres]>
    let error: Observable<Error>
    let isLoading: Observable<Bool>

    init(networking: Networking) {
        let result = networking.preformNetwokTask(endPoint: TheMoviedbApi.genre, type: Genre.self)
            .compactMap(\.genres)
            .materialize()
            .share(replay: 1)

        items = result
            .compactMap { $0.element }
        error = result
            .compactMap { $0.error }
        isLoading = result
            .map { _ in false }
            .startWith(true)
    }
}

final class GenreViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView!
    var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var viewModel: GenreViewModel!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.items
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { _, genres, cell in
                cell.textLabel?.text = genres.name
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.error
            .bind(onNext: presentScene(animated: true) {
                UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: $0.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    .scene { $0.connectOK() }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.isLoading
            .bind(to: activityIndicatorView.rx.isAnimating)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

In the above code, the network request will start as soon as the `bind` call is executed. If an error emits, it is routed to the `error` Observable and will display a UIAlertController with the error message (It uses the [CLE-Architecture-Tools](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools) to do this.) If it succeeds, the genres objects' names will be displayed in the table view.

Comment: i have adde the vc that i did

Comment: Can you please tell me what was missing in my example?
what is the trigger ?

Comment: In your particular case, there is no external trigger. The subscription itself was the trigger. Based on your code, that's what was throwing you off.

Comment: so viewModel.itemsDriver?.drive is not the trigger?
so how should i do it in my  example in order to trigger the network call?
subscribe?

Comment: In your second view model, you have `getGeners` which is acting as a trigger, but you aren't emitting a value. It's not enough to just subscribe in that case, your trigger must also emit a value.